# How to Resolve Missing Properties from Queried Models?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm using Typescript and Mongoose with GraphQL. Currently, when I query (i.e. execute `findOne`) a model the following issue arises:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Account': displayName, id, rpDisplayName

For context, below is the associated code. I'm confused as to why properties are considered "missing" from the resolved model.

---

```
import { Document, model, Schema } from "mongoose";

const AccountSchema = new Schema({
  entity: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["consumer", "provider"],
    default: "consumer"
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

export enum AccountEntity {
  CONSUMER = "consumer",
  PROVIDER = "provider"
}

export interface AccountModel extends Document {
  entity: AccountEntity;
  name: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
}

export interface AccountPayload {
  entity: AccountModel["entity"];
  name: AccountModel["name"];
}

const Account = model<AccountModel>("Account", AccountSchema);

export default Account;
```

---

```
import { QueryResolvers, QueryAccountArgs } from "../generated/graphql-types";
import Account from "../models/account";

const query: QueryResolvers = {
  account: (_: any, { payload }: QueryAccountArgs): Account =>
    Account.findOne({ _id: payload.id })
      .exec()
      .then(
        model => {
          if (!model) {
            throw Error(`Unable to find account with id ${payload.id}`);
          }
          return model;
        },
        reason => {
          throw Error(reason);
        }
      )
};

export default query;
```